# Extracting a tuple of value_type from a tuple of containers in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, boost-fusion

I have a function with a template parameter which I know to be a `std::tuple` of several standard C++ containers of varying element types.
How can I extract, out of this, a type that is a `std::tuple` of the element types?

For example, suppose I have the following function

```
template <typename TupOfCtrs>
void doStuff(const TupOfCtrs& tupOfCtrs) {
    using TupOfElements = /*extract a tuple type by applying CtrT::value_type to each container in tupOfCtrs and combining the results into an std::tuple*/;
    MyHelperClass<TupOfElements> helper;
}
```

and I know it is being called like this:

```
std::list<Foo> l {/*...*/};
std::vector<Bar> v {/*...*/};
std::deque<Baz> d {/*...*/};
auto tup = std::make_tuple(l, v, d);
```

In this case, I want the `TupOfElements` helper type to be defined as `std::tuple<Foo, Bar, Baz>`.
Note that I do not need to actually **create** the tuple, only to get its type.

How can this be achieved, possibly using the [**Boost::Fusion**](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/) library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this even in a more simple manner without Boost Fusion like this:

```
// Template which takes one type argument:
template <typename Tuple> struct TupOfValueTypes;

// Only provide a definition for this template for std::tuple arguments:
// (i.e. the domain of this template metafunction is any std::tuple)
template <typename ... Ts>
struct TupOfValueTypes<std::tuple<Ts...> > {
    // This definition is only valid, if all types in the tuple have a
    // value_type type member, i.e. the metafunction returns a type only
    // if all types of the members in the std::tuple have a value_type
    // type member, and a std::tuple can be constructed from these:
    using type = std::tuple<typename Ts::value_type...>;
};

template <typename TupOfCtrs>
void doStuff(const TupOfCtrs& tupOfCtrs) {
    using TupOfElements = typename TupOfValueTypes<TupOfCtrs>::type;
    // ...
}
```

But it is of course easier to specify `doStuff` for the `std::tuple` explicitly:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void doStuff(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tupOfCtrs) {
    using TupOfElements = std::tuple<typename Ts::value_type...>;
    // ...
}
```

**PS:** Also note, that in many cases if you need to just have a list of types, the `std::tuple` class is an overkill, and might slightly hurt compilation times. Personally, I've always instead used a simple `TypeList` struct:

```
template <typename ... Ts> struct TypeList
{ using type = TypeList<Ts...>; };
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want `doStuff` to take a `std::tuple`, make that explicit:

```
template <class... Ts>
void doStuff(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tupOfCtr) { ... }
```

Once you have that parameter pack, it's just a matter of pulling out the `value_type`:

```
template <class... Ts>
void doStuff(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tupOfCtr)
{
    using value_tuple = std::tuple<typename Ts::value_type...>;
    // ...
}
```